# Error in Programmatically Creating Paragraphs with Layout Paragraphs

Tags: 9, paragraphs, layout-builder

I am trying to programmatically create paragraphs using the *Layout Paragraphs* module. However, I'm encountering this error when saving the main entity that contains these paragraphs. I'm looking for guidance on the correct way to do this.

> In SqlContentEntityStorage.php line 811: paragraph.ERROR: Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (line 139 of /var/www/app/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php).

The code I am using is the following one.

```php
foreach ($json_data as $key => $value) {
  $paragraph = Paragraph::create([
    'type' => 'main_products',
    'field_id' => $link['id'],
    'field_text' => $link['text'],
  ]);

  // Set the layout
  $layoutSettings = [
    'layout_paragraphs' => [
      'layout' => 'layout_fourcol_section',
      'config' => ['label' => ''],
      'parent_uuid' => null,
      'region' => null,
    ],
    'mega_menu_behavior' => []
  ];

  $paragraph->setBehaviorSettings('layout_paragraphs', $layoutSettings);
  $current[] = $paragraph;
}

$mainEntity = MegaMenuLayoutBuilder::create([
  'type' => 'mega_menu_layout_builder',
  'langcode' => $locale,
  'field_menu_items' => $paragraphs,
]);

$mainEntity->save();
```

What is the correct way to programmatically generate content for paragraphs using layout_paragraphs?

Comment: Is that code snippet your custom code, or is that part of Drupal itself?

Comment: @cilefen custom code, is a part of a drush command in a class to import the data from json and create the content into a custom entity, all working less the paragraphs with layout paragraphs

Comment: What do you don't understand about the error message? Find the culprit getting an entity type definition with an empty string. Try xdebug or produce at least a full error message with stack trace.

Comment: @4uk4 the entity is correct in the case of the paragraphs and the custom entity data, I really debug, the issue is related with layout_paragraphs, need something else. because to the normal paragraphs work correctly.

Comment: OK, sometimes you can resolve this already if you enable full error messages with backtrace. See admin/config/development/logging. If not, then you need xdebug to check the variables why the entity type is an empty string.